# The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. - Error in AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I have following code :

```
$method = "GET";
$host = "payments-sandbox.amazon.com";
$uri = "/cba/api/purchasecontract/";
$private_key='PRIVATE_KEY';
$time = date('c');

$params = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => $private_key,
    'Action' => "CreatePurchaseContract",
    'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
    'SignatureVersion' => "2",
    'Timestamp' => $time);

uksort($params, 'strcmp');
$canonicalized_query = array();
foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
    $param = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($param));
    $value = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($value));
    $canonicalized_query[] = $param . "=" . $value;
}
$canonicalized_query = implode("&", $canonicalized_query);
$string_to_sign = $method . "\n" . $host . "\n" . $uri . "\n" . $canonicalized_query;
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $private_key, True));
$signature = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($signature));

echo $url = "https://payments-sandbox.amazon.com/cba/api/purchasecontract/"
 . "?Action=CreatePurchaseContract"
 . "&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256"
 . "&AWSAccessKeyId=$private_key"
 . "&Signature=".$signature
 . "&SignatureVersion=2"
 . "&Timestamp=" . $time;
```

But when i open url in new tab it's return following XML :

```
<ErrorResponse>
    <Error>
        <Type>Sender</Type>
        <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
        <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
    </Error>
    <RequestId>01a5de72-6e3f-11e4-85b3-9119f1b849cd</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

And it's give `The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.` error message when open `$url` link in new tab.

I dont know what's problem in creating signature??

**[UPDATE]**

I have try `cUrl` to fetch data :

```
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => $url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if(!$data){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
print_r($data);
```

But it's give me `Error: "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate" - Code: 60`. So what i do to fetch data from `payments-sandbox.amazon.com`

Comment: You should use their [SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/), saves you a lot of headaches.

Comment: what's problem in this code. I need solution in this..

Comment: @Ja͢ck How to use new [SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) instants of this code.??plz help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I tried to add my credentials with the `eb init` command in EB CLIx3.

It turned out I had mistyped my credentials every single time. I switched over to console for Windows where I could copy/paste my credentials. Now everything went without a hitch.

So copy/past credentials is my suggestion. If that doesn't work, you might want to create a new access key for a user with admin privileges. You can do that at the IAM section. Then try to copy past again.